# How to keep score value after reloading the html page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have been making a tictactoe game and I want to keep score of each of my winners, the thing is that once one of my players wins, a number is added to the score but once it refreshes to start the next match, the score goes back to 0
I think using localstorage is the key, but im not very familiar with it.
What would be the right approach to it?

```
//this is the variable that displays the score value 
let playx = document.getElementById('val');
```

```
function winnings(){

 alert('Player X WON!');
               
//here the value increments on each wining
               playx.innerHTML++; 

//I imagined this is how the value is stored
               localStorage.setItem('score', JSON.stringify(playx.innerHTML));

//this code below is to reload/restart the match
               maindiv[0].appendChild(parog);              
               setTimeout(reload, 2000);
...

}
```

```
// I tried to keep it after refreshing like this but once it reloads ot goes back to 0
(() =>{ 
 let score = localStorage.getItem('score').numeric
 
if(score === undefined ){
    playx.innerHTML = 0
}else {
    playx.innerHTML = score
}


})()
```

in applicatio/local storage,  shows key:innerHTML, value:0 and key:score value: "1"

Comment: `but that did not work`: did anything happen? Was there an error in the console? can you set your localStorage item to a variable and output it?

Comment: don't you need parseInt here (`playx.innerHTML++`)?

Comment: *"but that did not work"* - Nowhere in that attempt do you appear to **use** the value from `localStorage`.  Is your example incomplete?

Comment: @dbzx10299 I don't think so, playx value is already a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.innerHTML` returns a *string*, not a number.

Calling `localStorage.setItem('score', JSON.stringify(playx.innerHTML))` is placing `"'6'"` (for example) in localStorage. Why not just store as `localStorage.setItem("score", playx.innerHTML)`?

Parsing `"'6'"` or equivalent numbers will result in **NaN**, which is potentially causing your issues. Hard to tell without showing where you actually read the `getScore()` function

Comment: That is actually right, Im getting NaN , I have deleted getScore() did not do much and just pase it to a variable 'let score = localStorage.getItem('score')' which prints out '"1"' and tired 'playx.innerHTML = parseInt(score) but Im still getting NaN. How could that be solved?

Comment: You should not be storing `'"1"'` in localStorage, just `"1"` (string without quotation marks). Either don't stringify the integer before you store it, or get it from localStorage with `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("score")`. You're stringifying the data, but not parsing it back.